# Bounce button on tap

Tags: android, android-animation, android-button

does anybody know is there any xml animation that enables button to bounce for a few seconds. If you can and have share some examples...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a simple way to do it using an ObjectAnimator.  If you want this to work pre-honeycomb, you can either use the same syntax and do it with a [view animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html), or use [NineOldAndroids.](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

```
ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(button, "translationY", -100f, 0f);
animY.setDuration(1000);//1sec
animY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
animY.setRepeatCount(numRepeats);
animY.start();
```

Comment: How can we add this animation to more than one button,.? Actually button fall down one after another.?

Comment: add animY.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);. looks more beautiful and smooth

Answer (score 1):

```
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="0.5"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="0.5"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</set>
```

Above animation code put in anim folder and set it to any view using java code:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.bounce);
textview.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html) for some sample animations using a [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html). If you want to use it on APIs bellow HoneyComb you should try using [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) which is a port of the HoneyComb animations to lower APIs.